# AngularJS : how to wait until translation complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm developing application with AngularJS that prints business form.
Retrieve data from Google Cloud Endpoint, translate with angular translate, and open print dialog.

My application works in almost case, but sometimes print dialog opens before translation complete.

MyContoller.js is like this.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$location','errorServiceFactory',
    function ($scope,$location,errorServiceFactory) {
        var param = $location.search();
        $scope.list = [];
        loadingPanelFadeIn();
        gapi.client.myCloudEndpoint.retrieve({
            id:param.id,
        }).execute(function (resp) {
            if(!resp.code){
                loadingPanelFadeOut();
                $scope.list = resp.items;
                $scope.$apply();
                window.print();
            }else{
                errorServiceFactory.errorService(resp);
            }
            loadingPanelFadeOut();
        });

    }]);
```

html like this.

```
<div class="myclass" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <span class="big" style="(snip)" translate="title"> val1 </span>
    <span class="big" style="(snip)" translate="to" translate-values="{to: '{{item.field1}}'}"> val2 </span>
        :
```

In most case, translated value is displayed in print preview, but sometimes `val1 val2` is displayed.

How can I fix my program to open print dialog after translation completed?

Comment: Maybe try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: I need to see gapi.client.myCloudEndpoint.retrieve(), but if it returns a promise, you can use .then()

Comment: @MingShun, Thanks for your response. But what I'm facing is *not* retrieve from Google failed. Retrieve from Google is successful, but sometimes dialog opens before translation completes.

Comment: I get that, but translation itself is pretty-much instantaneous.  The only time it's asynchronous is when you're performing a server fetch for a translation list.  And that's generally done when you enter a page.  Basically, one of your other actions is asynchronous and doesn't always complete in time.  So you end up with invalid values that you feed into your translate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'resolve' to solve this problem.

just take some sentences from [the doc for resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

> "You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state."
>
> "If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired."

Answer (score 0):

Just hide content until DOM loaded

```css
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div ng-cloak>
 <div class="myclass" ng-repeat="item in list">
  <span class="big" style="(snip)" translate="title"> val1 </span>
  <span class="big" style="(snip)" translate="to" translate-values="{to: '{{item.field1}}'}"> val2 </span>
 </div>
</div>
```